# Realloc index of array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

Having an array as:

```
type **a;

a[0][data_0]
a[1][data_1]
a[2][data_2]
a[n][data_n]
```

When extending such an array by doing:

1. `realloc()` on `a` to `sizeof(type*) * (n + 1)`.
2. `malloc()` `(*a[n])` to fit `data_n` where `data_n` is of variable size.

Could there be some issue with `realloc()` of `a`?

As in `a[2]` would always point to `data_2`, even if `a` gets moved in memory, or could that link be lost?

As I understand it I end up with something like this in memory:

```
         Address               Address
a[0] => 0x###131, (*a[0]) => 0x####784
a[1] => 0x###135, (*a[1]) => 0x####793
a[2] => 0x###139, (*a[2]) => 0x####814
```

After `realloc()` I could end up with something like:

```
         Address               Address
a[0] => 0x###216, (*a[0]) => 0x####784
a[1] => 0x###21a, (*a[1]) => 0x####793
a[2] => 0x###21e, (*a[2]) => 0x####814
a[n] => 0x###zzz, (*a[n]) => 0x####yyy
```

Is this correct? The data_n segments are left alone, or could they also get moved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this correct? The data_n segments are left alone, or could they also get moved?

Yes, the values of `a[i]`, for `0 <= i < n` are copied to the new location, so the pointers point to the same `data_i` and those will not be moved.

> Could there be some issue with `realloc()` of `a`?

Of course, a `realloc` can always fail and return `NULL`, so you should never do

```
a = realloc(a, new_size);
```

but use a temporary variable to store the return value of `realloc`.

Comment: Thanks. Had to be 100% sure. Also as in if I have a separate ptr to data_nn it wont be corrupted after growing a. (I did a booboo by `realloc()` on a linked list - not to smart.)

Comment: Right, it won't be corrupted. `realloc` only knows the address and size of the current block, and the requested new size, it doesn't know what kind of data is stored there, so if it moves the block, it just copies the data (probably using `memcpy`).

Answer (score 2):

If you are reallocing to a larger size, the original bytes are unchanged.

Example:

```
char **a = malloc(n*sizeof(char *));
for (i=0; i!=n; ++i) {
  a[i] = malloc(m);
}

a = realloc(a,(n+1)*sizeof(char *));
// a[0]...a[n-1] are still the same
a[n] = malloc(m);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the address of old values remains same even after realloc()

You can see in the output of this program:

```
shubhanshm@BANLSHUBHANSH /cygdrive/f/My Codes/Practice/C
$ ./a.exe
Original Array details before using realloc():
Printing array with size 4x4
1       0       0       19
2       4       0       19
3       6       9       27
4       8       12      16
Printing array addresses with size 4x4
a[0][0]=1       ->0x20010260
a[0][1]=0       ->0x20010264
a[0][2]=0       ->0x20010268
a[0][3]=19      ->0x2001026c

a[1][0]=2       ->0x20010270
a[1][1]=4       ->0x20010274
a[1][2]=0       ->0x20010278
a[1][3]=19      ->0x2001027c

a[2][0]=3       ->0x20010280
a[2][1]=6       ->0x20010284
a[2][2]=9       ->0x20010288
a[2][3]=27      ->0x2001028c

a[3][0]=4       ->0x20010290
a[3][1]=8       ->0x20010294
a[3][2]=12      ->0x20010298
a[3][3]=16      ->0x2001029c

Array details after using realloc():
Printing array with size 5x4
1       0       0       19
2       4       0       19
3       6       9       27
4       8       12      16
5       10      15      20
Printing array addresses with size 5x4
a[0][0]=1       ->0x20010260
a[0][1]=0       ->0x20010264
a[0][2]=0       ->0x20010268
a[0][3]=19      ->0x2001026c

a[1][0]=2       ->0x20010270
a[1][1]=4       ->0x20010274
a[1][2]=0       ->0x20010278
a[1][3]=19      ->0x2001027c

a[2][0]=3       ->0x20010280
a[2][1]=6       ->0x20010284
a[2][2]=9       ->0x20010288
a[2][3]=27      ->0x2001028c

a[3][0]=4       ->0x20010290
a[3][1]=8       ->0x20010294
a[3][2]=12      ->0x20010298
a[3][3]=16      ->0x2001029c

a[4][0]=5       ->0x20048300
a[4][1]=10      ->0x20048304
a[4][2]=15      ->0x20048308
a[4][3]=20      ->0x2004830c
```

The source code for the above output is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define mul(x, y) (((x)+1)*((y)+1))

void printArr(int **a, int r, int c){
    int i, j;
    printf("Printing array with size %dx%d\n", r, c );
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void printArrAddress(int **a, int r, int c){
    int i, j;
    printf("Printing array addresses with size %dx%d\n", r, c );
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
            printf("a[%d][%d]=%d\t->%p\n", i, j, a[i][j], &a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    int **a;
    int n = 4;
    a = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i< n; i++){
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(i+1));
        for(j = 0; j < i+1; j++ )a[i][j] = mul(i, j);
    }
    printf("Original Array details before using realloc():\n");
    printArr(a, n, n);
    printArrAddress(a, n, n);

    a = (int**)realloc(a, sizeof(int*)*(n+1));
    a[n] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    for( i = 0; i< n; i++){
        a[n][i] = mul(n, i);
    }
    printf("Array details after using realloc():\n");
    printArr(a, n+1, n);
    printArrAddress(a, n+1, n);
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this clarifies things.